# Check radiobutton on label click in angular Mat Dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, modal-dialog, angular-reactive-forms

I tried creating custom rating bar in angular, and it appears to be working fine in a simple component, but I had to move it to MatDialog and it caused certain problems.
In initial set up my input is set to `display: none`, since radio button can be checked when clicked on label. (again, works good in simple components)
In MatDialog component I cannot check it on label click anymore. Is there something I missed? What is causing the problem?

Thanks in advance for your ideas!

My app-new-review-modal.html:

```html
<mat-dialog-content>
<form [formGroup]="rate">
    <div class="rating" >
      <input type="radio" value="5" name="rateStar" id="star5" formControlName="rateStar">
      <label for="star5"></label>
      <input type="radio" value="4" name="rateStar" id="star4" formControlName="rateStar">
      <label for="star4"></label>
      <input type="radio" value="3" name="rateStar" id="star3" formControlName="rateStar">
      <label for="star3"></label>
      <input type="radio" value="2" name="rateStar" id="star2" formControlName="rateStar">
      <label for="star2"></label>
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="rateStar" id="star1" formControlName="rateStar">
      <label for="star1"></label>
    </div>
  </form>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

My controller:

```
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-review-modal',
  templateUrl: './new-review-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-review-modal.component.scss']
})
export class NewReviewModalComponent implements OnInit {
  rate: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    })

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rate = this.fb.group({
      rateStar: []
    });
  }

}
```

css (if needed):

```
.rating {
  width: 155px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 20px;
  direction: rtl;

  label {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #676767;

    &:before {
      content: "\2605";
    }
  }

  input {
    display: none;
  }

  input:checked ~ label,
  label:hover ~ label,
  label:hover {
    color: rgb(120, 140, 116);
  }

}
```

Comment: Make Z-index of rating bar higher than that of matDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  rate: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rate = this.fb.group({
      rateStar: new FormControl()
    });

    this.setValue("4"); // default value
  }

  setValue(rateStar: string): void {
    this.rate.patchValue({ rateStar });
  }
}
```

you can get your value in HTML like this -

```
<p>
  {{this.rate.get('rateStar').value}}
</p>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-heyrovsky-kpj13?from-embed